# Complex number: Roots

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

> Solve all the roots of the following equation: $$(z-i)^2(z+i)^2=\frac{1}{4}.$$ Find the set of complex numbers $z$ such that $$\left|\frac{z-3}{z+3}\right|=2.$$

Would anyone mind telling me how to solve the above problems? I really have no idea.

Comment: Let $z = x + iy $ in the second one and use the definition of absolute value.

Comment: This is not helpful, but: You *solve* an equation, which means that you *find* its *roots*. You do **not** *solve roots*.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, you have $(z-i)(z +i) = z^2 + 1$.  This should help you get there.

For the second, you might want to square both sides and clear the fraction.

Try these things and see if they help.

Answer (score 2):

The first one:

$$(z-i)^2(z+i)^2 = \left( (z-i)(z+i) \right)^2 = (z^2 - i^2)^2 = (z^2+1)^2,$$

so

$$z^2+1 = \pm\frac{1}{2}.$$

For the second one, write $z = x + iy$, so $|z-3| = 2|z+3|$, which is equivalent to $|z-3|^2 = 4|z+3|^2$, gives you

$$(x-3)^2 + y^2 = 4(x+3)^2 + 4y^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINTS:**

**1.** Difference of two squares.

**2.** We can show with a bit of work that

$$\left|\frac{z_1}{z_2}\right|=\frac{|z_1|}{|z_2|}.$$

What *might* help then is if you know what $|z-a|$ is geometrically.